# ¿Por que la funciona mail retorna false?

Tags: php

realize la configuracion del php ini y el smtp pero aun asi la funcion mail 
Abajo ejemplo

```
mail('israejjjjjjjj.0@gmail.com','hola','holaquehace')
```

me retorna false intente con
Abajo ejemplo

```
mail('israeldbksabkag@gmail.com','hola','hhoajljla\r\n')
```

y lo mismo
este es mi php.ini

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
SMTP = smtp.gmail.com
; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port = 465

; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
;sendmail_from = me@example.com

; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -i").
; http://php.net/sendmail-pathabajovacia
sendmail_path =C:\Bitnami\wampstack-7.1.17-0\sendmail\sendmail.exe -t

; Force the addition of the specified parameters to be passed as extra parameters
; to the sendmail binary. These parameters will always replace the value of
; the 5th parameter to mail().
;mail.force_extra_parameters =

; Add X-PHP-Originating-Script: that will include uid of the script followed by the filename
mail.add_x_header = Off

; The path to a log file that will log all mail() calls. Log entries include
; the full path of the script, line number, To address and headers.
;mail.log =
; Log mail to syslog (Event Log on Windows).
;mail.log = syslog
```

me sale el siguiente error
**Socket Error # 11001Host not found.**

Comment: A simple vista el código PHP se ve bien. ¿Cómo configuraste el smtp? ¿Aparece algo en los logs?

Comment: Intenta capturar el error de este modo: `$bolEnviar=mail('israeldbksabkag@gmail.com','hola','holaquehace'); if($bolEnviar){
    echo "Mensaje enviado exitosamente";
}else{
    echo "Hubo un error ".error_get_last()['message'];
}` De todos modos, prueba algo más completo, poniendo las cabeceras, como indica el [**Ejemplo 2**  del Manual de PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/function.mail.php).

Comment: intente usar error_get_last() no me devuelve nada en los log tampoco

Comment: configure los smtp como sale en este video  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xJvwtwjovMQ y descargue sendmail

Comment: intente con el segundo ejemplo y nada

Comment: ¿Podrías volver a revisar la configuración en `php.ini` y compartirla en la pregunta (sólo lo relativo a `mail` no todo el archivo). Lo puedes agregar al final, [editando la pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/197131/edit).  Revisa que no haya configuraciones repetidas en el archivo de configuración.